# javascript: change attributes of multiple div's inside other div

Tags: javascript

I have table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="mbusTable">
    <label><h5>rtu</h5></label>
    <tbody>
        <td><input type="text" id="mid" class="span1" placeholder="mid"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="type" class="span1" placeholder="typem"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="inverce" class="span1" placeholder="inverce"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mbaddr" class="span1" placeholder="mbaddr"></td>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

All I want is to add `_mbusTable` to all inputs inside it. Here's what I have now:

```
        function correctIDs(tableID)
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            var prefix = tableID;
            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                prefix += "_" + table.childNodes[1].getAttribute('id');
                table.childNodes[1].setAttribute('id',prefix);
                prefix = tableID;
            }
        };
```

But I guess it changes only first `<input>`. How can I jump to the next?
Sorry if it's something obvious. Thanks

Comment: I don't think `label` inside `table` as a direct child is valid

Comment: Have you option to use Jquery?

Comment: Ok, then I append him after all.

Comment: Acutally, I came up first time with this in js: `table.rows[0].cells.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function correctIDs(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var prefix = tableID + "_" + inputs[i].getAttribute('id');
        inputs[i].setAttribute('id', prefix);
    }
};


correctIDs("mbusTable");
```